# Unable to Set Variable from within ExpressJS res.locals.connection.query() statement

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

I am attempting to create a Single Sign-On feature that checks if a user is already provisioned, and either Creates a user or updates the database with the latest information.

I have gotten the update/insert working, but now I am unable to return the users id (uid or UserID), from the query.

I have left several of the things I have tried commented in the section.

Basically, the query that does the insert/update is nested inside of another, which is inside of the post_assert. I need the value of iresults.insertId for users that were just provisioned and the result of results[0].nid from the first level query to be saved into the 'cookieData' array.

Right now, I'm getting the rest of the cookie (firstName, lastName, username, email, wwwid, country and geo, but for the life of me cannot get the cookieData.userid property to be added to it before it gets sent back to the browser.

This is an expressJS REST API that sends data back to a VueJS Application.

I have tried callbacks as well as global variables, but nothing seems to add the new value to the Array.

```js
sp.post_assert(idp, options, function (err, saml_response) {
        if (err)
            res.redirect('https://www.example.com/');
        var sessionID = saml_response.response_header.id;
        setCookie(res, req, sessionID);
        var refererLocation = req.cookies.referLocation;
        // Set User Data Variables
        const firstName = saml_response.user.attributes.givenName;
        const middleName = null;
        const lastName = saml_response.user.attributes.sn;
        const username = saml_response.user.attributes.uid;
        const email = saml_response.user.attributes.mail;
        const wwid = saml_response.user.attributes.employeeID;
        const country = saml_response.user.attributes.country;
        const geo = saml_response.user.attributes.geographicRegion;
        /*function setCookieData(val) {
          cookieData.userid = val;
        }*/
        // let userid;
        // Check if user exists in DB
        res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', [username], function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) throw error;
          // Get the Current Date-Time for insertion
          const accessDateTime = new Date();
          const adtYear = accessDateTime.getFullYear();
          const adtMonth = accessDateTime.getMonth() + 1;
          const adtDay = accessDateTime.getDate();
          const adtHour = accessDateTime.getHours();
          const adtMin = accessDateTime.getMinutes();
          const adtSec = accessDateTime.getSeconds();
          const dts = `${adtYear}-${adtMonth}-${adtDay} ${adtHour}:${adtMin}:${adtSec}`;
          // let userid;
          // If results is empty, then the user who just logged in does not currently have
          // an account provisioned, so set them up an account.
          if (!(results.hasOwnProperty(0))) {
            res.locals.connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {first_name: firstName, middle_name: middleName, last_name: lastName, username: username, email: email, status: 1, created: dts, access: dts, login: dts}, function (ierror, iresults, ifields){
              if (ierror) throw ierror;
              // Set the User Data Cookie
              // res.locals.userid = iresults.insertId;
              // setUserIdValue(iresults[0].insertId);
              // res.clearCookie('UserInfo');
              // res.cookie('UserInfo', cookieData);
              // cookieData.userid=iresults[0].insertId;
              // res.cookie('UserInfo', cookieData);
              app.locals.userid = iresults[0].insertId;
            });
          // Else, the result was NOT empty, then the user already exists in the DB,
          // so just update their Access and Login DATETIME fields.
          } else {
            res.locals.connection.query('UPDATE users SET login = ?, access = ? WHERE uid = ?', [dts, dts, results[0].uid], function (ierror, iresults, ifields){
              if (ierror) throw ierror;
              // userid = results[0].uid;
              // Set the User Data Cookie
              // res.locals.userid = results[0].uid;
              // setUserIdValue(results[0].uid);
              // res.clearCookie('UserInfo');
              // res.cookie('UserInfo', cookieData);
              // cookieData.userid=results[0].uid;
              // res.cookie('UserInfo', cookieData);
              app.locals.userid = results[0].uid;
            });
          }
        });
        const cookieData = {
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          username: username,
          email: email,
          wwid: wwid,
          country: country,
          geo: geo,
          userid: app.locals.userid,
        };
        res.cookie('UserInfo', cookieData);
        //Add saml ID to database with expiration date
        if (refererLocation != undefined) {
            res.clearCookie("referLocation");
            res.redirect('https://www.example.com' + refererLocation);
        } else {
            res.redirect('https://www.example.com/uri');
        }
        // Save name_id and session_index for logout
        // Note:  In practice these should be saved in the user session, not globally.
        // name_id = saml_response.user.givenName + "," + saml_response.sn;
        // session_index = saml_response.user.session_index;
        //var first = saml_response.user.attributes.givenName;
        //var last = saml_response.user.attributes.sn;
        //res.send("Hello, " + first + " " + last);
    });
```

## EDIT (9-11-2018)

I have broken it down to it's most simplest concept, and am still unable to get it to return the 'userid' value into the cookie. Even after setting everything to ASYNC and AWAIT.

```js
app.post('/api/v1/saml/acs', function (req, res) {
    const options = {
        request_body: req.body,
        allow_unencrypted_assertion: true
    };
    sp.post_assert(idp, options, async function (err, saml_response) {
        if (err)
            res.redirect('https://www.example.com/');
        const sessionID = saml_response.response_header.id;
        const user = saml_response.user.attributes;
        // Set User Data Variables
        const firstName = user.givenName;
        const middleName = null;
        const lastName = user.sn;
        const username = user.uid;
        const email = user.mail;
        const wwid = user.employeeID;
        const country = user.country;
        const geo = user.geographicRegion;
        app.locals.UserData = {
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          username: username,
          email: email,
          wwid: wwid,
          country: country,
          geo: geo,
          // userid: '',
        };
        // Check if user exists in DB
        await res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', [app.locals.UserData.username], async function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) throw error;
          // Get the Current Date-Time for insertion
          const accessDateTime = new Date();
          const adtYear = accessDateTime.getFullYear();
          const adtMonth = accessDateTime.getMonth() + 1;
          const adtDay = accessDateTime.getDate();
          const adtHour = accessDateTime.getHours();
          const adtMin = accessDateTime.getMinutes();
          const adtSec = accessDateTime.getSeconds();
          const dts = `${adtYear}-${adtMonth}-${adtDay} ${adtHour}:${adtMin}:${adtSec}`;
          // If results is empty, then the user who just logged in does not currently have
          // an account provisioned, so set them up an account.
          if (!(results.hasOwnProperty(0))) {
            await res.locals.connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {first_name: app.locals.UserData.firstName, middle_name: app.locals.UserData.middleName, last_name: app.locals.UserData.lastName, username: app.locals.UserData.username, email: app.locals.UserData.email, status: 1, created: dts, access: dts, login: dts}, async function (ierror, iresults, ifields){
              if (ierror) throw ierror;
              app.locals.UserData.userid = 22;
              // app.locals.UserData.userid = iresults.insertID;
            });
          } else {
            await res.locals.connection.query('UPDATE users SET login = ?, access = ? WHERE uid = ?', [dts, dts, results[0].uid], async function (ierror, iresults, ifields){
              if (ierror) throw ierror;
              app.locals.UserData.userid = 44;
              // app.locals.UserData.userid = results[0].uid;
            });
          }
        });
        // Set User Session Cookie
        res.cookie('UserData', app.locals.UserData);
        // Set SAML Session Cookie
        setCookie(res, req, sessionID);
        // Get the referrer location
        var refererLocation = req.cookies.referLocation;
        // If it is undefined, then send the user back to where they started the Sign On process.
        if (refererLocation != undefined) {
            res.clearCookie("referLocation");
            res.redirect('https://www.example.com' + refererLocation);
        } else {
            res.redirect('https://www.example.com/uri');
        }
    });
});
```

## Response to dmfay

I believe I have followed your advice, but it is still not returning the 'userid' property.

I have added the 'next' parameter to

```
app.post('/api/va/saml/acs', function (){...});
```

and added a 'next()' call at the end of

```
sp.post_assert(idp, options, async function(...){
    // logic here with nested calls trying to update app.locals.UserData
    next();
});
```

I have also tried the 'next()' call outside of the post_assert, and I get this message:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

See below for the updated code.

```js
app.post('/api/v1/saml/acs', function (req, res, next) {
    const options = {
        request_body: req.body,
        allow_unencrypted_assertion: true
    };
    sp.post_assert(idp, options, async function (err, saml_response) {
        if (err)
            res.redirect('https://www.example.com/');
        const sessionID = saml_response.response_header.id;
        const user = saml_response.user.attributes;
        // Set User Data Variables
        const firstName = user.givenName;
        const middleName = null;
        const lastName = user.sn;
        const username = user.uid;
        const email = user.mail;
        const wwid = user.employeeID;
        const country = user.country;
        const geo = user.geographicRegion;
        app.locals.UserData = {
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          username: username,
          email: email,
          wwid: wwid,
          country: country,
          geo: geo,
          // userid: '',
        };
        // Check if user exists in DB
        await res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', [app.locals.UserData.username], async function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) throw error;
          // Get the Current Date-Time for insertion
          const accessDateTime = new Date();
          const adtYear = accessDateTime.getFullYear();
          const adtMonth = accessDateTime.getMonth() + 1;
          const adtDay = accessDateTime.getDate();
          const adtHour = accessDateTime.getHours();
          const adtMin = accessDateTime.getMinutes();
          const adtSec = accessDateTime.getSeconds();
          const dts = `${adtYear}-${adtMonth}-${adtDay} ${adtHour}:${adtMin}:${adtSec}`;
          // If results is empty, then the user who just logged in does not currently have
          // an account provisioned, so set them up an account.
          if (!(results.hasOwnProperty(0))) {
            await res.locals.connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {first_name: app.locals.UserData.firstName, middle_name: app.locals.UserData.middleName, last_name: app.locals.UserData.lastName, username: app.locals.UserData.username, email: app.locals.UserData.email, status: 1, created: dts, access: dts, login: dts}, async function (ierror, iresults, ifields){
              if (ierror) throw ierror;
              app.locals.UserData.userid = 22;
              // app.locals.UserData.userid = iresults.insertID;
            });
          } else {
            await res.locals.connection.query('UPDATE users SET login = ?, access = ? WHERE uid = ?', [dts, dts, results[0].uid], async function (ierror, iresults, ifields){
              if (ierror) throw ierror;
              app.locals.UserData.userid = 44;
              // app.locals.UserData.userid = results[0].uid;
            });
          }
        });
        // Set User Session Cookie
        res.cookie('UserData', app.locals.UserData);
        // Set SAML Session Cookie
        setCookie(res, req, sessionID);
        // Get the referrer location
        var refererLocation = req.cookies.referLocation;
        // If it is undefined, then send the user back to where they started the Sign On process.
        if (refererLocation != undefined) {
            res.clearCookie("referLocation");
            res.redirect('https://www.example.com' + refererLocation);
        } else {
            res.redirect('https://www.example.com/uri');
        }
        next();
    });
});
```

## Working Code

Thank you DMFAY and BennetQuigley. This issue has been resolved.

The working solution is commented below.

```js
app.post('/api/v1/saml/acs', function (req, res, next) {
    const options = {
        request_body: req.body,
        allow_unencrypted_assertion: true
    };
    sp.post_assert(idp, options, function (err, saml_response) {
        if (err)
            res.redirect('https://www.example.com/');
        // Get the Sessions ID
        const sessionID = saml_response.response_header.id;
        // Set the returned User Info to a Variable
        const user = saml_response.user.attributes;
        // Set the app.locals.UserData variable
        app.locals.UserData = {
          firstName: user.givenName,
          middleName: null,
          lastName: user.sn,
          username: user.uid,
          email: user.mail,
          wwid: user.employeeID,
          country: user.country,
          geo: user.geographicRegion,
        };
        // Check if user exists in DB
        res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', [app.locals.UserData.username], function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) throw error;
          // Get the Current Date-Time for Insert/Update of user logon history
          const accessDateTime = new Date();
          const adtYear = accessDateTime.getFullYear();
          const adtMonth = accessDateTime.getMonth() + 1;
          const adtDay = accessDateTime.getDate();
          const adtHour = accessDateTime.getHours();
          const adtMin = accessDateTime.getMinutes();
          const adtSec = accessDateTime.getSeconds();
          const dts = `${adtYear}-${adtMonth}-${adtDay} ${adtHour}:${adtMin}:${adtSec}`;
          // If results is empty, then the user who just logged in does not currently have
          // an account provisioned, so set them up an account.
          if (!(results.hasOwnProperty(0))) {
            res.locals.connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {
              first_name: app.locals.UserData.firstName,
              middle_name: app.locals.UserData.middleName,
              last_name: app.locals.UserData.lastName,
              username: app.locals.UserData.username,
              email: app.locals.UserData.email,
              status: 1,
              created: dts,
              access: dts,
              login: dts
            }, function (ierror, iresults, ifields){
              if (ierror) throw ierror;
              // set the app.locals.UserData.userid value to the newly inserted ID
              app.locals.UserData.userid = `["${iresults.insertID}"]`;
              // From here to 'next()' has to be repeated in both cases
              // 'next()' must be used to return the values and actions to the parent
              // Call.
              // Set User Session Cookie
              res.cookie('UserData', app.locals.UserData);
              // Set SAML Session Cookie
              setCookie(res, req, sessionID);
              // Get the referrer location
              var refererLocation = req.cookies.referLocation;
              // If it is undefined, then send the user back to where they started the Sign On process.
              if (refererLocation != undefined) {
                  res.clearCookie("referLocation");
                  res.redirect('https://clpstaging.mcafee.com' + refererLocation);
              } else {
                  res.redirect('https://clpstaging.mcafee.com/clp');
              }
              // Tell the callback to move forward with the actions.
              next();
            });
          } else {
            res.locals.connection.query('UPDATE users SET login = ?, access = ? WHERE uid = ?', [dts, dts, results[0].uid], function (ierror, iresults, ifields){
              if (ierror) throw ierror;
              // Set the app.locals.UserData.userid to the Users PK
              app.locals.UserData.userid = results[0].uid;
              // From here to 'next()' has to be repeated in both cases
              // 'next()' must be used to return the values and actions to the parent
              // Call.
              // Set User Session Cookie
              res.cookie('UserData', app.locals.UserData);
              // Set SAML Session Cookie
              setCookie(res, req, sessionID);
              // Get the referrer location
              var refererLocation = req.cookies.referLocation;
              // If it is undefined, then send the user back to where they started the Sign On process.
              if (refererLocation != undefined) {
                  res.clearCookie("referLocation");
                  res.redirect('https://www.example.com' + refererLocation);
              } else {
                  res.redirect('https://www.example.com/uri');
              }
              // Tell the callback to move forward with the actions.
              next();
            });
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Still looking for some help on this. I've even tried splitting each of the levels into it's own ASYNC function and forcing to AWAIT on each internal function or call.

Comment: oops, I didn't notice something else in your structure -- everything from `res.cookie('UserData', ...)` on down needs to be _inside_ the `SELECT` query callback, not just inside the `post_assert` callback. Bennett mentioned promises which are a good way to avoid this kind of "pyramid of doom" effect callbacks have, as long as everything you're using has a promise API.

Comment: When I put everything from res.cookie('UserData', ...) down into either of the other res.locals.connection.query() callbacks I get the error:

` Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

I have put it both Inside the IF and ELSE statements of if `(!(results.hasOwnProperty(0))){...}` check as well as directly after the else statement.  Inside of the if statment, I have also tried it both inside and directly after the nested `res.locals.connection.query(''){...}` calls, all of which give me the same error as above.

Comment: Every time the execution path reaches a callback, you shouldn't be doing anything else after & outside that callback. Right now you're going post_assert -> select -> insert OR update (my bad, hadn't had coffee). If you need to set your locals in the insert/update callbacks then that's where you need to set the cookie (both places). Also making these async functions really isn't doing anything, async functions await promises and you aren't using promises.

Comment: Perfect. This works, thank you both so much.

I'll be placing the final working code into an update in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post_assert callback is async but your route callback is not, so the route logic completes before the post_assert callback can finish. Probably your easiest recourse with Express is to use the `app.post(url, function (req, res, next) {...})` signature and invoke `next()` as the last step in the post_assert callback once you've finished writing the cookie and setting up the redirect.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I have added this into my code and am still not getting the app.locals.UserData.userid into the res.cookie('UserData',app.locals.UserData) call.

I do get all of the values that are set manually from when app.locals.UserData is defined.

I have updated the question with more details for this reply.

Answer (score 1):

As dmfay said, post_assert completes & sets the cookie before the query can complete and set the userid field.

The best way I found to solve these types of issues are to use [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises).

From Google's documentation on Promises:

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // query the database to get the user id

  if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!"); //resolve (return) the user id here
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});
```

And then you'll want to utilize what the Promise returns.

```js
promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // Set the cookie with the user id here
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err); // Error
});
```