# How to return result after all queries executed

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am using the following code to save/update records using Node.js:

```
router.route('/SaveData').post(VerifyToken, function(req, res) {
    new sql.ConnectionPool(conn).connect().then(pool=>{
        pool.request()
            .input('userid', sql.NVarChar(50), req.body.userid)
            .execute("USP_Save1").then(function(ret) {
                if (req.body.array1 != undefined) {
                    req.body.array1.forEach(function(p) {
                        pool.request().input('lng_Distance', sql.Int, p.lng_DistanceFromWinch).execute("USP_Save2")
                    });
                }
            });
        return pool.request()
            .input('AssetID', sql.VarChar, req.body.AssetNumber)
            .execute("USP_GetAllUpdatedRecords")
    }).then(result=>{
        let rows = result
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type,  X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
        res.status(200).json(rows);
        sql.close();
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "${err}",
            err
        })
        sql.close();
    });
});
```

**Problem:** In above code as you can see I am saving header and array1. But in callback I am getting result before record updated in database. How can I apply Promises here?

**Working Copy**

Adding this so that we can look at what works and what doesn't.

I have moved the SELECT query to execute directly after it exits the req.body.array1.forEach() loop. This would mean it only gets the updated ones if the IF statement is evaluates. To select regardless of if there was an update, move it just after the if and see if that works.

```
router.route('/SaveData').post(VerifyToken, function(req, res) {
    new sql.ConnectionPool(conn).connect().then(pool=>{
        pool.request()
            .input('userid', sql.NVarChar(50), req.body.userid)
            .execute("USP_Save1").then(function(ret) {
                if (req.body.array1 != undefined) {
                    req.body.array1.forEach(function(p) {
                        pool.request().input('lng_Distance', sql.Int, p.lng_DistanceFromWinch).execute("USP_Save2")
                    });
                return pool.request()
                    .input('AssetID', sql.VarChar, req.body.AssetNumber)
                    .execute("USP_GetAllUpdatedRecords")
                }
            });
    }).then(result=>{
        let rows = result
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type,  X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
        res.status(200).json(rows);
        sql.close();
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "${err}",
            err
        })
        sql.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: I actually just resolved an issue similar to this. What worked for me was to put all of my output into the inner-most request. Try putting everything from the `.then(...)` statement into the `.execute(...)`.  What seemed to be happening is that it was sending back the inner most request before the outer requests could finish.  Here is a link to my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263614/unable-to-set-variable-from-within-expressjs-res-locals-connection-query-state

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion, But i am getting error when i am putting then in inner function. Can you edit my sample? so that i can understand more this.

Comment: I will add an additional working copy to your question so that we can work through it. I don't want to put an answer up because I don't have a way to test it.